# Top 3 of each group by time of day - SQL Lite

Tags: sqlite

I'm currently learning how to use SQL Lite, and would like to sort the top 3 most popular pickup locations by hour. I have millions of rows of data with columns of interest being lpep_pickup_datetime (Pickup time) and POLocationID (Pickup location).

I'd like to the top 3 most popular pickup locations by hour.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
    +----------------------+--------------+-----------------+
    | lpep_pickup_datetime | PULocationID | passenger_count |
    +----------------------+--------------+-----------------+
    | 1/1/2017 0:01        |           42 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:03        |           75 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:04        |           82 |               5 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:01        |          255 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:00        |          166 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:00        |          179 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:02        |           74 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:15        |          112 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:06        |           36 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:14        |          127 |               5 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:01        |           41 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:31        |           97 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:01        |          255 |               5 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:00        |           70 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:03        |          255 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:03        |           82 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:00        |           36 |               1 |
    | 1/1/2017 0:01        |            7 |               1 |
    +----------------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

Trying this on SQLLiteStudio 3.2.1 - might I just need to use a full MySQL suite in order to be able to use the proper functions?

```
SELECT 
PULocationID, count(PULocationID)
FROM GreenCabs2017
GROUP BY PULocationID
ORDER BY count(PULocationID) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The query I've tried only returns top 3 pickup locations across the entire dataset and not by hour of day - how would I be able to group by hour of day? Other solutions on StackExchange reference date_time and date_format functions that won't execute when I try them on SQL Lite - what's a query that would work on SQL Lite?

Ideally would have something like the below:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| Time of Day | PULocationID | PULocationCount |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
| 0:00        |           74 |             677 |
| 0:00        |           65 |             333 |
| 0:00        |           55 |             220 |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

This would be the output for top 3 pickup locations from midnight to 1:00 AM. This time range would have to apply across all the dates, i.e. 1/1 to 1/31 and not just 1/1 like the sample I provided.

UPDATE:
Changed the format of the timestamps to be YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format, so I can use the datetime functions now.

Was able to run a query which I think may bring me much closer to what I'm looking for:

```
SELECT lpep_pickup_datetime, PULocationID, count(PULocationID)
FROM GreenCabs2017
WHERE STRFTIME('%Y', lpep_pickup_datetime) = '2017' AND
      STRFTIME('%H', lpep_pickup_datetime) <= '01' AND
      STRFTIME('%H', lpep_pickup_datetime) >= '00'
GROUP BY PULocationID
ORDER BY count(PULocationID) DESC
LIMIT 3
```

That gave an output of

```
+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| lpep_pickup_datetime | PULocationID | count(PULocationID) |
+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 1/31/2017 1:13       |          255 |                7845 |
| 1/31/2017 1:04       |            7 |                4596 |
| 1/31/2017 1:07       |           82 |                3892 |
+----------------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

But the lpep_pickup_datetime column still indicates that this would be in between 1:00 AM and 2:00 AM and not 12:00 AM and 1:00 AM? Removing the "=" sign in the query results in no results being returned. And I would prefer to not do this for every hour in the day - would there be a way to have an output by hour through one query?

Comment: @Shawn OK just transformed all the timestamps to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format...would one of the five SQLLite functions allow me to group by hour overall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamp string format your data is using, `m/d/YYYY H:MM`, is not very good. It can't be used by sqlite [date and time functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), can't be meaningfully ordered for sorting, and in general is very hard to work with in sqlite. Remember, sqlite [does not have](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) dedicated date or time types, just strings or numbers, so the format you're using has to obey the rules of those types. So your first step is to, by whatever means, fix those timestamps. The following assumes you changed them to `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM` strings like `2017-01-01 00:01`, or another compatible format. It also assumes you're using a fairly recent sqlite release, as it uses [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html) which were added in 3.25.

(Edit: You appear to be using NYC taxi data from [here](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/tlc/about/tlc-trip-record-data.page), which has timestamps in a good format already, and is suitable for easy importing into sqlite. That makes it trivial to fix.)

Given all that, this query:

```sql
WITH ranked AS
 (SELECT hour, PULocationID, pickups
       , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY hour ORDER BY pickups DESC) AS rn
  FROM (SELECT strftime('%H:00', lpep_pickup_datetime) AS hour
             , PULocationID
             , count(*) AS pickups
        FROM GreenCabs2017
        GROUP BY strftime('%H:00', lpep_pickup_datetime), PULocationID))
SELECT * FROM ranked
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY hour, rn
```

will give, for NYC Green Cab data for January 2017

```
hour        PULocationID  pickups     rn        
----------  ------------  ----------  ----------
00:00       255           4224        1         
00:00       7             2518        2         
00:00       82            2135        3         
01:00       255           3621        1         
01:00       7             2078        2         
01:00       256           1870        3         
02:00       255           3261        1         
02:00       256           1798        2         
02:00       7             1676        3         
03:00       255           2854        1         
03:00       256           1589        2         
03:00       7             1475        3
```

and so on.

Basically, it counts the number of times each location appears in each hour, and for each hour, assigns each location a row number based on sorting by that number. Then only the first three rows of each hour are returned in the final outer select. You can also use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`, which will potentially return more than 3 rows per hour in case of ties but also more accurately reflect the most popular locations in those cases.

---

(This query benefits a lot from having an index on the group by expression:

```
CREATE INDEX greencabs2017_idx_hour_loc ON GreenCabs2017(strftime('%H:00', lpep_pickup_datetime), PULocationID);
```

)

Test table created from the sqlite3 shell via:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import '|curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyctlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2017-01.csv | sed 2d' GreenCabs2017
```

Comment: Just ran the CREATE INDEX function, but when I tried to run your WITH ranked AS query, it's returning a syntax error? Is there something simple I'm missing with the way I'm inputting it...it returns an error at the first parentheses

Comment: @mazuka487 You're probably using an outdated version of sqlite.

Comment: OK was able to get it to run using the DB Browser for SQLLite - thank you so much for your help on this!

Comment: Any thoughts on why there's so many pickups with a NULL timestamp? Based on the output, that would indicate that there's 160,000+ rows with NULL timestamps?

Comment: @mazuka487 `strftime()` returns null when it gets a time string that's not a known format. (The timestamps in the original CSV data files are ideal as-is, btw.)

Comment: @mazuka487 1070261 rows. There's a blank line between the header line and actual data for some reason. (I added how I populated a test table in my answer)